# Failover Access Database in ASP Classic

Tags: ms-access, asp-classic, adodb, failover

I am developing a website in ASP Classic that is required to connect to an Access database (.accdb) via an ADODB connection. See my working connection script below:

```
Set objConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set objRS = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

objConn.Open "DSN=my_database"

strSQL = "some query"

set objRS = objConn.Execute (strSQL)
```

This DSN is actually a Microsoft Access driver linked to an .accdb file. I have no choice but to work within this constraint.

I am trying to find a way to failover to a copy of this Access database while the main one is being backed up, otherwise the site becomes inaccessible during that time.

Does anyone know how to fail over to a different DSN if the first one is inaccessible?

Comment: Can't you use an OLEDB connection string which points directly to the ACE database - eg `Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\path-to\yourdb.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;`

Comment: And anyway surely all you need to do to back up a file database is to make a copy of the file, do you really need to take it offline.

Comment: To be more clear, the database for the website is being updated by copying another instance of that same database over it.  If there is another way of connecting to the daabase (like through an OLEDB) connection, I'm not sure what I would need to change in my connection script to implement that.  Would it look like this? objConn.Open "DSN=Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\path-to\yourdb.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;"   And if so, I don't see how that provides a way to failover when the database is inaccessible.

Comment: The connection string would look like `objConn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\path-to\yourdb.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;`, You could easily change the file location to a different accdb file.  I still don't see how overwriting one accdb with another is going to take more than a second or two
https://www.connectionstrings.com/access/

Comment: Large accdb being copied over slow network.  Does  that connection support the failover partner option or alternate data source (to automatically connect to if the first is unreachable)?

Comment: Two suggestions.  If you use an `If....Else` conditional statement to specify alternative connection strings you could try to trap the error number (Google VBScript error reporting) and use that as a condition to use the backup connection, or if the overwriting is a scheduled event - eg 10-12pm every Sunday you could use the date and times in your condition.

Comment: If you have a slow network connection then couldn't you copy to a different location on the server then overwrite the live database only when the network transfer is complete.  And if it's a really big addcb file then it might be worth thinking about upgrading to SQL Server.  You can import an accdb file into SQL Server

Comment: As already suggested - do not overwrite or backup large db file over
    the network but place a copy of the file (and rename to required name
    *after* the transfer is completed). For better user experience, check db and do "please wait" if locked. If this is about getting a new data - consider import instead of fileover, i.e. instead of replacing entire live db file, take and copy new data to the live database.

Comment: I appreciate all of these suggestions.   I ended up using a combination of many of the suggestions.  For starters I am updating the database over the network and then copying it over the live database locally, which seems faster and less error prone.   I am also testing importing the access data into a local SQL database so that the site can stay online during database update.